# What is the correct version for Box Android sdk

Tags: box-api

I go http://developers.box.com/onecloud/ to download the Android SDK. I got box-box-android-sdk-5482811 Is this the latest version?

Because when I open up the OneCloudAppToAppSample, even the R. variable is not well defined. And I cannot run the sample code.

Where can I find more help or documentation on using Box with Android SDK?

Answer (score 1):

The SDK is being improved quite frequently, so our advice would be to always use the latest version on the "master" branch. We consider the master branch to be our stable release.  In your case, 5482811 should work fine.

Regarding your issues with the sample app, I don't seem to have any problems compiling it off of a fresh download. I can think of one thing you might be running into:

The sample app was configured to point to target "Google APIs:15".  It's possible you don't have this installed (through the Android SDK manager). We actually should not have configured this build target, since the project doesn't use the Google APIs, and we'll fix that in our next release.

In the meantime, could you try this (assuming you're using Eclipse):

1. Right-click on the OneCloudAppToAppSample project and go to Properties.
2. Go to the Android section on the left, and change the build target to Android 4.0.3 - 15 (not the Google APIs version).
3. Project -> Clean -> Clean all projects.